# Is it possible to pass `host_name` via Measurement Protocol for GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm using the Measurement Protocol to push e-commerce events to GA4 and it works well. The [screenshot shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03SP1.png) an example of the data I'm passing from the backend.

Additionally, I'd like to pass `host_name` parameter, however, looking through the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference?client_type=gtag#payload) I didn't find any information on support for it. Is there a way to pass this as well?

In the case of the Measurement Protocol for Universal Analytics, hostname can be passed by declaring it as `dh` (eg: `'dh' => 'www.domain.com'`), but this does not work with GA4.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at this document [API Dimensions & Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema),
Depending on your requirements you may use `fullPageUrl` which is a dimension  that returns the host-name, page path, and query string for web pages visited.

Or you can use `page_location` [Automatically collected events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069?hl=en). Just remember that if you want to use page_location you should create customised dimension named exactly page_location.

In order to create custom dimension ([Creating Custom Dimension and Metric](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en)), log into your analytics.google account and then

- Access the “Configure” menu in GA4 and click into “Custom definitions”.
- Click to create a new dimensions.
- Choose the scope of the custom dimension (user or event), which in this case is `Event`.
- Name your custom dimension, which in this case in page_location.
- Define the Event parameter of your custom dimension, which in this case in page_location.
- Save your custom dimension. It takes 48 hours for Google to effect the modifications.
  [image]

This tutorial also explains about how to See Full Page URLs in Google Analytics 4.

[GA Full Page URL](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/full-page-urls-in-google-analytics-4/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! In my case, the `page_location` parameter worked. **After I started passing it, the hostname dimension also started populating automatically.**

Comment: That's a fascinating obervation @shila. How did you discover the requirement to create a custom definition for auto-collected attributes such as `page_location` ? I've just added those myself, but I'll have to wait 2 days to see the results.

Comment: @Trip: I do not remember how I ended up in this solution but I know why :D, Since I did not want to lose my job :DDDD

Comment: @ShilaMosammami YOU WERE TOTALLY RIGHT! Thank you so much. The answer is adding those as explicit definitions. I hope one day to buy you a cup of coffee for that one. :D